# How to add Haskell (or) operator to a variable with "isPrefixOf"

Tags: haskell

I'm not a Haskell developer but I had to deal with a quick fix. I have search the Haskell documentation and Stackoverflow in vain. It looks like I'm dealing with unreadable syntax.

I have the following variable that checks if a parameter has a prefix of "book-", and I'm trying to add "or" operator to this variable so I can check against `book-` or `cover-` prefix.

```
isSessionVariable :: Text -> Bool
isSessionVariable = T.isPrefixOf "book-" . T.toLower
```

My expectations is something like:

```
isSessionVariable :: Text -> Bool
isSessionVariable = T.isPrefixOf ("book-" || "cover-") . T.toLower
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
isSessionVariable :: Text -> Bool
isSessionVariable name = T.isPrefixOf "book-" (T.toLower name) || T.isPrefixOf "cover-" (T.toLower name)
```

Or, preferably, don't call `toLower` twice:

```
isSessionVariable :: Text -> Bool
isSessionVariable name = T.isPrefixOf "book-" lowerName || T.isPrefixOf "cover-" lowerName
  where
    lowerName = T.toLower name
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there's no built-in way to do this with `Text`.

This is because `T.isPrefixOf` takes a Text of (say) 5 characters, and compares this Text to the first 5 characters of your original Text. If all 5 are equal, boom. End of.

What you're implicitly asking is a more complicated version of `T.isPrefixOf`.

One non-fancy way to achieve what you want is:

```hs
isSessionVariable :: Text -> Bool
isSessionVariable source = T.isPrefixOf "book-" source || T.isPrefixOf "cover-" source
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! While your answer was the first and helped me to fix it. However, I have to go with Fyodor answer as it consider "toLower" case.